Fourier transform of a symbolic function
In Mathematica: How can I compute the Fourier transform of a symbolic function $x\partial_y f(x,y)$?. I know that, $(x\partial_y f(x,y))^{\wedge}(\xi,\eta)=\xi \partial_\eta \widehat{f}(\xi,\eta)$.
